# BFS on Adjacency Matrix

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a BFS on adjacency matrix of undirected unweighted graph which returns the number of nodes visited. I've come up with this till now but I think this is not right as when I print out the top/ visited node, I'm getting multiple occurrences of some nodes as well as it's not sorted. I've read somewhere that BFS is a topological sort and the order I get is not sorted.

```
int BFS(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &matrix, int start)
{
    std::vector<bool> visited(matrix.size(), false);
    std::queue<int> Q;
    Q.push(start);
    int count = 0;

    while( ! Q.empty())
    {
        int top = Q.front(); Q.pop();
        visited[top] = true; count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(matrix[top][i] != 0 && (! visited[i]) )
            {
                Q.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you think it's right?

Comment: I was just editing the question to add that and you downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote. :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of setting `visited` node to true after popping the queue, you should set it when you insert it to the queue, and add count inside as well, as to prevent double counting of some nodes. Please refer to the following:

```
//..previous lines

Q.push(start);
visited[start] = true;
int count = 1;

while(!Q.empty()){
    int top = Q.front(); Q.pop();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i){
        if(matrix[top][i] != 0 && (! visited[i]) ){
            Q.push(i);
            visited[i] = true;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I arrived at the answer as well by hit and trial, but fundamentally the for loop is for adding all the neighbours of the visited node, right ?
And isn't it the same if we visit it when we're removing from the Queue or should I just add (not in Queue) when doing the if ?

Comment: no, it's not the same. example: say u have (1)->(2), (3) and (2)->(3). If you count++ when you pop the queue, the (3) node is counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

There a few questions, to help us hone the answer. But, please share more details on the count that you get back. Here are the things to look at:

- Why do you increment the count inside the for loop? You are possibly counting a node multiple times.
- The size of *Visited* isn't sufficient to hold all the nodes. In `std::vector<bool> visited(matrix.size(), false);`, matrix.size() returns only the outer vector's size. It means that at most one row worth of data is available in *Visited*.
- The data structure used for *Visited* is problematic. Either you use a vector> or a linearized vector that has n*n elements in one sequence. If you end up using a simple vector, you need to map a [i][j] index into a position when you look up the index in *Visited*. This is a major issue and you cannot track the nodes correctly.
- Sorted order is not guaranteed out of a BFS. Please construct a simple counter example to convince yourself. Topological Sort can be performed using BFS(or DFS).

Comment: That count was left by mistake as I forgot to remove it after trying different variations. I've edited and removed it now.


I believe, the visited array can hold all nodes as the adjacency matrix will be n*n if the graph has n nodes. Hence, visited can take care of all nodes.


Ok, it may not perform a sort always, but it is not supposed to visit the same node multiple times. I added a print statement for top after visited[top] = true and found repetition of nodes which I think does not happen in BFS.

Comment: You are missing one key point: in the declaration of visited, you specify the size as matrix.size(). But, matrix is a vector of vector. When you say matrix, size(), you get the outer vector's size. But, visited may potentially need to have all the elements.

Comment: But the number of elements = size of outer matrix as it's an adjacency matrix.